# How to provide a file share for a stateless service running in Azure Service Fabric cluster?

Tags: file-storage, azure-service-fabric

I am deploying a stateless API that has a file upload method. The API consumer uploads a file and the file is stored in the file system (network share) and the metadata is stored in the database.

However, when it is deployed to the Azure environment, I don't really know how to configure the service to be able to access Azure Files which supports SMB.
The Service Fabric Mesh seems to support File volume driver but I am not using service mesh. Just good old Service Fabric.

So can you please recommend a way of not having to rewrite my file i/o so that it works in Azure with the File storage.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows#persisting-azure-file-share-credentials-in-windows) a mount to the file share. Use a service principal to access the storage credentials, or put them in configuration.
Run the script as a [setup entry point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-run-script-at-service-startup) of the service.
Make sure the script runs [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence).

```
$resourceGroupName = "<your-resource-group-name>"
$storageAccountName = "<your-storage-account-name>"

# These commands require you to be logged into your Azure account, run Login-AzAccount if you haven't
# already logged in.
$storageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $storageAccountName
$storageAccountKeys = Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $storageAccountName

# The cmdkey utility is a command-line (rather than PowerShell) tool. We use Invoke-Expression to allow us to 
# consume the appropriate values from the storage account variables. The value given to the add parameter of the
# cmdkey utility is the host address for the storage account, <storage-account>.file.core.windows.net for Azure 
# Public Regions. $storageAccount.Context.FileEndpoint is used because non-Public Azure regions, such as sovereign 
# clouds or Azure Stack deployments, will have different hosts for Azure file shares (and other storage resources).
Invoke-Expression -Command ("cmdkey /add:$([System.Uri]::new($storageAccount.Context.FileEndPoint).Host) " + `
    "/user:AZURE\$($storageAccount.StorageAccountName) /pass:$($storageAccountKeys[0].Value)")
```